# RecycleView's setInitialPrefetchItemCount is not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm trying to improve the user experience while scrolling a grid of images by prefetching views ahead of time using the new API introduced in the support library 25.1 for controlling the number of prefetched items in a RecycleView.

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this.getContext(), PhotoGridViewHolder.SPAN_SIZE);
layoutManager.setItemPrefetchEnabled(true);
layoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(30); 
photosRecycleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
... add 100 photos to the adapter ...
```

And I also added logging for my ViewHolders so I could see if the binding really happened.

```
void bind(final Photo photo, int position) {
    // I expcet to see 30 logs without event scrolling as the intial set to 30.
    log.d("binding photo: " + photo.getId());
    loadPhoto(photo);
}
```

However, it seems like it's not working, as I loaded a list of 100 images but I see only a few log entries (just fetching the visible items), but I'd expect to see at 30 as I set it to be like so.

Answer (score 6):

As @FlanschiFox and comments below his answer says, this is only working for inner RecyclerViews. Additionally, I wrote a `PreloadLinearLayoutManager` [here](https://github.com/HJWAJ/RecyclerViewThings/blob/5535b2d61c56c445bf0e13caaf47884cc93bcec7/app/src/main/java/com/hjwaj/myapplication/prefetch/PreloadLinearLayoutManager.java) to preload data 5 items before the list scrolls to the end. It may help you a bit.

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful.

Comment: @HJWAJ, I checked your class and works when scrolling, but how do I preload the n items without scrolling?

Comment: @makkhaygurung prefetch is designed to optimize scrolling performance. If you are using `LinearLayoutManager`, you can override `LinearLayoutManager#getExtraLayoutSpace` to preload items. Unfortunately I didn't find any way to preload with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`.

Comment: See Android Docs: "Calling this method does nothing unless the LayoutManager is in a RecyclerView nested in another RecyclerView", https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager#setinitialprefetchitemcount

Comment: @HJWAJ You wonderful human, it worked!!! I'm on xamarin and your preload class worked for me after a little tweaking. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, this is only working for inner RecyclerViews.

Documentation: [isItemPrefetchEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#isItemPrefetchEnabled())

> Sets the number of items to prefetch in collectInitialPrefetchPositions(int, LayoutPrefetchRegistry), which defines how many inner items should be prefetched when this LayoutManager's RecyclerView is nested inside another RecyclerView.

Comment: According to this article, it's not only for nested recycle views:
https://medium.com/google-developers/recyclerview-prefetch-c2f269075710

Comment: The article says: Performing this work for nested RecyclerViews [..] is trickier ... This is the reason for the new API in v25.1 of LinearLayoutManager, setInitialItemPrefetchCount(), which tells the system how many items to prefetch to fill the RecyclerView

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the nested recycler view cases. However, how many items are prefetched when using one of the default layout managers and a flat recycler view?

Comment: default is 2 @AvidProgrammer